# UML: signal classifier vs class classifier

Tags: java, uml

If I understand signal right this is an asynchronous message between two or more objects. For example in UML we have a signal classifier:

```
-----------------
|  << signal >> |
|  SomeEvent    |
-----------------
|id:Int         |
|text:String    |
-----------------
|getId()        |
|getText()      |
-----------------
```

Then we can write this signal in Java as following:

```
class SomeEvent{
  private final int id;
  private final String text;
  //+constructor + getters
}
```

However, in Java we have a CLASS, but in UML we have a SIGNAL classifier, but not a CLASS classifier(**Update: I mean in this example**). How to explain it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your discussion about UML signals is correct.

From the spec.:

> **10.3.3.1 Signals**
>
> A Signal is a specification of a kind of communication between objects in which a reaction is asynchronously triggered
>   in the receiver without a reply. The receiving object handles Signals as specified by clause 13.3. The data carried by the
>   communication are represented as attributes of the Signal. A Signal is defined independently of the Classifiers handling
>   it.

---

> However, in Java we have a CLASS, but in UML we have a SIGNAL classifier, but not a CLASS classifier. How to explain it?

1. UML does have a CLASS classifier, from the spec. (emphasis mine):

> **11.4 Classes**
>
> ... The purpose of a Class is to specify a classification of objects and to specify the Features that characterize the **structure and behavior of those objects**.
>
> **11.4.4 Notation**
>
> A Class is shown using the Classifier symbol. As Class is the **most widely used Classifier**, **no keyword is needed** to indicate that the metaclass is Class.

2. UML is programming-language-independent.

   In Java, UML class and signal classifiers are implemented as classes.

   Another example: UML has a interface classifier, but C++ does not have
   interfaces. An interface in C++ would be an abstract (pure virtual) class.

Comment: you may want to mention that the intent expressed in UML gets lost in translation to Java.

Answer (score 2):

In fact UML is richer than Java.
In UML, Signal, Class, Component, and Collaboration classifier concepts would correspond to Java Class.